# gitlab-ci.yml, before_script and artifact

Tags: gitlab, artifact

In [gitlab-ci.yml documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README.md#before_script-and-after_script), it says that

> before_script is used to define the command that should be run before all
>   jobs, including deploy jobs, but after the restoration of artifacts.

This tells me that artifact is produced before a job start running

But the [artifact documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.md#introduction-to-job-artifacts) says that

> Artifacts is a list of files and directories which are attached to a
>   job after it completes successfully

This tells me that artifact is produced after a job finish running.

This is a contradiction. Can someone please explain how this is not a contradiction?

I imagine they are talking about the artifact in previous job? But I don't know how artifact and job work and can be wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Artifacts can be produced by build jobs from one stage and consumed by build jobs from the next stage. So before_script is run after the artifacts produced by the previous stage are restored for the current stage.

So the follwing .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - echo "before_script"
  - ls

build_artifacts:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "build_artifacts"
    - touch build_output
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build_output

test_artifacts:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "test_artifacts"
```

Will give the following outputs:

```
# build_artifacts job
$ echo "before_script"
before_script
$ ls
README.md
$ echo "build_artifacts"
build_artifacts
$ touch build_output
Uploading artifacts...
build_output: found 1 matching files               
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=56026 responseStatus=201 Created token=xxxxzzzz
Job succeeded



# test_artifacts job
Downloading artifacts for build_artifacts (56026)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=56026 responseStatus=200 OK token=xxxxzzzz
$ echo "before_script"
before_script
$ ls
README.md
build_output
$ echo "test_artifacts"
test_artifacts
Job succeeded
```

As you can see the test_artifacts job downloads the artifacts before the `before_script` runs.